# Divergence of Random Harmonic Series

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider the random series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/n$ where $X_n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p.$ I am asked to show that this series diverges almost surely by modifying the usual proof of divergence of the harmonic series. I consider the sums $$P_k = \frac{X_{2^k+ 1}}{2^k + 1} + \cdots + \frac{X_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k + 1}} $$ This sum has $2^k$ terms, each term either 0 (with probability $1-p$) or at least $1/2^{k+1}$ (with probability $p$). As a hint I am asked to compute an upper bound for $\mathbb{P}[P_k< p/8].$ <s>My attempt: P_k< p/8 means that strictly fewer than $2^{k-2}$ terms are nonzero, and the probability of that event is precisely the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{2^{k-2}-1}\binom{2^k}{j}\frac{p}{2^{k+1}}$
I don't see any way to either evaluate or quickly estimate this sum,</s> I don't see a way to apply a well-known concentration inequality to the hint nor do I see a way to use such an *upper bound* to complete a Borel-Cantelli argument; the events $P_k$ are all clearly independent, but should I not be looking at lower bounds as with the standard harmonic series? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, fewer than $2^{k-2}$ terms are non-zero means $P_k < 1/4$, not $P_k < p/8$.  I don't know how to solve the whole problem, but comparing $P_k$ to $p/8$ reminds me of Markov's inequality, since (1) the mean is linear on $p$ so $p/8$ is a fixed fraction of the mean, and (2) everything here is positive so Markov applies.  But I'm not sure Markov is strong enough.

Comment: You are right, of course, my mistake. Regarding Markov; I thought so too, but wouldn't Markov yield an upper bound on $\mathbb{P}[P_k>p/8]$ instead? And if I flip the inequality here, Markov is then a lower bound, which might be what I'm actually supposed to do to complete the Cauchy argument, but I can't see how.

Comment: You're right, a straightforward use of Markov won't work here.  I haven't had a chance to work this out, sorry.  My original comment was simply meant to point out your mistake to hopefully "unblock" you.  :)  Maybe Chebyshev's inequality?  Although I don't see a straightforward application either.  Good luck!